# Page navigation Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm new to android apps and xamarin.

I'm trying to build an android app, which exists of 2 views.
1 view with a listview, and 1 view to add a new item to the listview.
My idea is that whenever you press the button, the second view appears.
And when you click on the button add, it switches back to the first view.

I thought this code would work:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync (new ContactPage());
```

But as you can see,

[image: Navigation not being recognized]

The term Navigation is not being recognized.

Comment: If you are using Pages in `Xamarin.Forms` the `Navigation` Property should be recognized by compiler as it  exists in `VisualElement`. Please see [VisualElement.Navigation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Navigation/). Could you please post some more codes or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: you are using `xamarin.forms` tag in your question which is confusing everyone. And `Navigation` is under namespace `xamarin.forms` please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found the solution.
First of all it is not possible to have a App.cs file if you don't use cross-platform, which in my case is true.

To solve the problem, you have to use another method, which is called android Multiscreen. [Here's](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/hello,android_multiscreen_quickstart/) a link if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I see in your code is using await with Navigation, it's not needed their.Second It seems like you are just setting your first page as MainPage in *App.cs*.
In order to use the Navigation class in *Xamarin.Forms* you have to first create NavigationPage instance usually people do that in *App.cs* like following :

```
MainPage = New NavigationPage (New ContentPage());
```

And then in any page they can use navigation by using following code like

```
Navigation.PushAsync(New ContentPage());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see an app.cs in my solution explorer.

Comment: @DannyBunschoten Have you hosted your code anywhere like github if yes then share the url and I will have a look. Ideally if it's a Xamarin.Forms application then there must be a App class inherited from Application clazz. Check for that class.if you don't get app.cs file

Comment: Then it will tough to help you out sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Navigation with NavigationPage.